# Few of the lines of code are not getting executed intermittently in Protractor

Tags: typescript, promise, protractor

I am calling a function from my test which makes a call to an API service and returns a value. I am able to print the value of the variable from my test that is being returned, every time. However the lines of code after that are not getting executed.
This is happening intermittently.

main function:

```
it('Test1', function () {
  element(by.xpath("xpath of the element1")).click();
  response = homepo.getValuefromAPI();
  response.then(function(value){
    console.log("**********value inside Main*****************");
    console.log((value)); 
    element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);
    browser.sleep(3000);
    element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();
    expect(value).toBe("expected value");
  });
});
```

Function which returns a promise:

```
getValuefromAPI(){
var deffered = protractor.promise.defer();
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  headers:
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body:
    {json body},
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  let responseData = JSON.stringify(body);
  console.log("**********responseData inside function*****************");
  console.log(responseData);
  console.log("*******************Id*****************");
  console.log(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id);
  deffered.fulfill(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id);
});
return deffered.promise;
}
```

Output:

```
**********responseData inside function*****************
ABCDFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
*******************Id*****************
ABCDFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
**********value inside Main*****************
ABCDFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
x Test1
  - Expected 'ABCDFEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' to be 'expected value'.
```

The 'sendKeys' action and the 'click' action after that (in the main test) are skipped most of the times and the control directly jumps to the 'expect' statement. Sometimes these are statements get executed without any issues.

Is there something wrong with the way I am handling promise?

**Update** : Now I have also tried executing the api call inside 'it' block instead of returning the value. However, still the lines are not getting executed.

```
it('Test1', function () {
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  headers:
    { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  body:
    { 
    json body
    },
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    let responseData = JSON.stringify(body);
    console.log("**********responseData inside function*****************");
    console.log(responseData);
    console.log("*******************Id*****************");
    console.log(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id); 
    element(by.xpath("xpath of the element1")).click();
    console.log("**********value inside Main*****************");
    console.log((value)); 
    browser.sleep(2000);   //This line is not getitng executed
    element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);   //This line is not getitng executed
    browser.sleep(2000);   //This line is not getitng executed
    element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();   //This line is not getitng executed
    browser.sleep(2000);   //This line is not getitng executed
    expect(value).toBe("expected value");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed for me by adding a wait and a return statement as mentioned below:

```
getValuefromAPI(){
  var deffered = protractor.promise.defer();
  return browser.wait(function() {
    var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    headers:
      {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body:
      {json body},
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    let responseData = JSON.stringify(body);
    console.log("**********responseData inside function*****************");
    console.log(responseData);
    console.log("*******************Id*****************");
    var id = body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id;
    console.log(id);  
    deffered.fulfill(id);
  });
  return deffered.promise;
  }, 10000).then(function(){
    return id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it('Test1', function () {
  element(by.xpath("xpath of the element1")).click();
  response = homepo.getValuefromAPI();
//it will only execute when the value is set
    if(!!response){
          response.then(function(value){
            element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);
            browser.sleep(3000);
            element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();
            expect(value).toBe("expected value");
           });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Victor. But the issue is still happening. I have added a print statement inside if condition to print the returned value. That is being executed, as expected. And then the control goes to the expect statement without executing the in between statements.

Comment: Any idea why am I seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the returned promise which you are storing in "value" does not change. So, even after the following actions

```
element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);
browser.sleep(3000);
element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();
```

it'll remain same. So it doesn't matter where you put `expect(value).toBe("expected value");`
Try putting `expect(value).toBe("expected value");` right at the beginning of promise :

```
response.then(function(value){
    expect(value).toBe("expected value");
    console.log("**********value inside Main*****************");
    console.log((value)); 
    element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);
    browser.sleep(3000);
    element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();
  });
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, The Expect command was just to test whether the control comes inside the response,then() block. It does not matter whether it is executed or not. I could see that the 3 lines that I need to work is not getting executed correctly but the control comes to the Expect command without any errors. Now even if I add the expect statement at the beginning of the promise, it will get executed but the rest of the lines will be skipped.

Comment: That's strange . Can you define the elements at the beginning(before promise) as variable and use the variables inside the promise?

You're saying console.log works but it skips the .sendKeys() and .click()?

Comment: Yes. The console.log works but it skips the .sendKeys() and .click().

Comment: Declare/define the web elements as variables before promise and use it inside promise to perform actions. See if it helps

Comment: Hi Avinash, The lines are still getting skipped even after declaring the web elements as variable at the starting of 'it' block.

Comment: Hi Praveen, try using the callback as ive posted in the new answer. If it doesn't help, I'm sorry, running out of option. 
One question, the API basically returns just a string right??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this one. Instead of using return from the API function, try using callback as shown :

```
getValuefromAPI(callback){
var deffered = protractor.promise.defer();
var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'url',
  headers:
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body:
    {json body},
};
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  let responseData = JSON.stringify(body);
  console.log("**********responseData inside function*****************");
  console.log(responseData);
  console.log("*******************Id*****************");
  console.log(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id);
  deffered.fulfill(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id);
});
callback (deffered.promise);
}
```

Your calling function would look something like this :

```
  it('Test1', function () {
          element(by.xpath("xpath of the element1")).click();
          homepo.getValuefromAPI(function(response){
            response.then(function(value){
                 console.log("**********value inside Main*****************");
                 console.log((value)); 
                 element(by.xpath("xpath of the element2")).sendKeys(value);
                 browser.sleep(3000);
                 element(by.xpath("xpath of button']")).click();
                expect(value).toBe("expected value");
               });
          });   
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash for the reply. I am not sure why but the callback is not getting recognized in my code. It says: "TS2304: cannot find name 'callback'". Anyways my code is working now with a small change I did. Mentioned the code below as answer.